# Quote issues when counting individual words in a large text file

Tags: java, regex

I need to create code to count individual words in a .txt file. The format has to be similar to:

```
the - 10
text - 1
has - 5
etc.
```

I am experiencing an issue that I cant seem to resolve: 
The text uses apostrophes for quoes, so my codes parses words like 'don't , and doesn't see 'don't as the same as don't. I don't know how to fix this.

This is the specific part of the code. I have to use regular expressions in a delimiter.

```
static int findAndCountWords (Scanner scanner, String[] words, int [] freqs)
{
    assert (words != null)&&(freqs != null): "findAndCountWords doesn't work.";
    int nr=0;
    while (scanner.hasNext())
    {   
        String word = scanner.next();
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        scanner.useDelimiter("[^a-z]");
        //|[^a-z]+[\\'][^a-z]+
        if (updateWord(word, words, freqs, nr))
        nr++;
    }
    return nr;
}
```

Comment: What about adding the apostroph? `.useDelimiter("[^a-z']")` ?

Comment: You might get started with the deliminter `"\\W*\\s+\\W*"`.

Answer (score 0):

I would trim any apostrophes from your words first.

You can do this with Apache commons:

```
str = StringUtils.stripStart(str,"'")
```

or your your matcher:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:^')|(?:'$)); // starts or ends with apostrophe
str = pattern.matcher(str).replaceAll(""); // not anymore
```

(I did not test the code, maybe some bug)